# Add YYYY, MM, DD dropdown lists for selecting a date on a webpage

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add the dropdown style date selector which repopulates the date list according to the selected year and month eg. february 2008 has 29 days, april has 30 days while june has 31 days etc... How can i do this using javascript?

Comment: yes, to select one's date of birth...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help

http://javascript.internet.com/forms/date-selection-form.html

I would recommend to use

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Answer (score 1):

Is this what your searching for ?

http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<select name="" id="year">
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
</select>
<select name="" id="month">
    <option value="0">January</option>
    <option value="1">February</option>
    <option value="2">March</option>
    <option value="3">April</option>
    <option value="4">May</option>
    <option value="5">June</option>
    <option value="6">July</option>
    <option value="7">August</option>
    <option value="8">September</option>
    <option value="9">October</option>
    <option value="10">Novenmer</option>
    <option value="11">December</option>
</select>
<select name="" id="day">

</select>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            dpick('#year','#month','#day',1);
        });

        function dpick(year,month,day,td){
            if(td==1){
                var today = new Date();
                $(year).val(today.getFullYear());
                $(month).val(today.getMonth());
            }
            $(year).change(function(){
                dpick(year,month,day);
            });
            $(month).change(function(){
                dpick(year,month,day);
            }); 
            var month_val = $(month).val();
            var i=0;
            $(day).empty();
            if(month_val=="1"){
                if($(year).val()%4 == 0){
                    for(i=1;i<=29;i++){
                        $(day).append($("<option></option>").attr("value", i).text(i));
                    }
                }else{
                    for(i=1;i<=28;i++){
                        $(day).append($("<option></option>").attr("value", i).text(i));
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(month_val=="8" || month_val=="3" || month_val=="5" || month_val=="10"){
                for(i=1;i<=30;i++){
                    $(day).append($("<option></option>").attr("value", i).text(i));
                }
            }
            else{
                for(i=1;i<=31;i++){
                    $(day).append($("<option></option>").attr("value", i).text(i));
                }
            }
            if(td==1){
                $(day).val(today.getDate());
            }
        }
    </script>
```